# Lorentz transform of light cone vectors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

I'm currently taking classes on Special Relativity and Minkowski space. I have one question: how would future-oriented, contravariant time-like, space-like and light-like vectors transform under a Lorentz transformation?

Comment: Have you tried a calculation of a boost applied to such vectors? You can start with the 1+1 case. You should find that the tips move along distinct hyperboloids, where the light cone is a degenerate hyperboloid of radius [interval] zero.

Comment: Light-like vectors are eigenvectors, that is point. Just visualise the skew.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir Though in n+1 for n > 1 dimensions, *not* all lightlike vectors are eigenvectors.

Comment: Oh yes. Light-like vectors in the plane of a Lorentz boost are eigenvectors, sorry. Also worth asking if the OP means just "Lorentz boost" by "Lorentz transformation", or if he's including rotations.